# Quartz.Net - Providing own DateTimeService

Tags: quartz.net

I have an application that is using quartz.net which is time based i.e. certain jobs execute at certain points of time. Now for the purpose of testing I want to advance time on the hosting server to prove that all works as intended. The problem I have is on our corporate network you cant advance time, all the servers, pcs are synchronised.

What I wanted to do is create a DateTimeService that my application would use anytime it needed to get the current datetime. Sounds good to me, where the problem lies is there anyway I can make quartz.net use this service???

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Imho you can replace the func delegate in the static class `SystemTime`:

https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz/SystemTime.cs

by setting

```
SystemTime.UtcNow = () => new DateTime(2011,1,2);
```

to set to a static time, or replace it with a func delegate to your service.

Comment: Additional information: you'll need to recompile quartz.net in order to do that. The SystemTime class is not being injected, but is being used as static instead.

Comment: SystemTime is a delegate so you can replace it with another delegate without recompiling even if it's a static function pointer you can let it point wherever you want.